# How to change url php parameter to subdomain and as a variable

Tags: php, apache, web, subdomain

i want to do it but i don't know how to, i've tried a lots of tutorials but doesn't work for me.

I have a website (PHP), that show several info depending of a parameter on URL (i interpret it with php) like this:

*example.com/about.php?some=1*

i want to change the URL to:

*some.example.com/about.php*

and get the subdomain name (some) and use it as a PHP variable.

**Important: i should use this function on all my website (as a $_SESSION variable but through URL)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the subdomain from the `SERVER_NAME` environment variable:

```
$subdomin = (explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))[0];
var_dump($subdomain);
```

So if you hit `some.domain.com`, you'll get:

```
string(4) "some"
```